# Is there any evidence of heterosexual men being sexually attracted to women breasts pre-Victorian history?

Tags: sexuality, sex

I read some articles which say men's sexual attraction to breasts (during sex or casually) is because culture/society started it. One relevant article is [this](https://medium.com/swlh/the-human-body-is-not-inherently-sexual-so-why-do-we-make-it-the-case-for-womens-96efe3c12482#:%7E:text=They%20are%20hyper%20sexualizing%20this,the%20female%20body%20oppresses%20us.&text=Because%20in%20our%20culture%2C%20women%27s,even%20conscious). Women were told to hide breasts and hence men got sexually attracted to them because everyone loves what's hidden (I read answers on Quora and Reddit which wrote all these things).

I read many discussions by some experience users on Reddit, who commented above things, especially "everyone loves what's hidden" (talking about breasts).

They gave basically 2 reasons for saying this:

1. There are women in Africa who go topless and men *don't care* about it like everyone else in most other cultures (Read this kind of views on Reddit)
2. In Victorian era, [ankles](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-30052071) were considered sexual, because they were hidden and because they were hidden men would get turned on (Read on Quora answers)

So, I'm just getting curious - Did this sexual attraction to breasts really started when culture/society started to hide breasts and eventually they became sexual attraction?

**Is there any evidence in known history that sexual attraction to breasts (and importance of breasts during sex) was also common in past, especially before Victorian era?**

Note: Most of the things I wrote above I mainly I read on Yahoo answers, Reddit, Quora and few users on StackExchange users in comments of past questions on various SE sites. And I could relate them because I have already read so many articles mentioning similar things about [Victoria era](https://www.bl.uk/romantics-and-victorians/articles/victorian-sexualities#) and culture/society [sexualized](https://arcanelost.com/sexualization-of-breasts/) breasts.

One reference about breasts role in human sexual activity is mentioned in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breast) article.

One answer [here](https://www.quora.com/When-and-how-did-breasts-become-sexualized-in-western-culture) talks about "not a natural attraction".

Comment: The OP should provide their sources, starting with the articles they read etc. But: Erotic writing exists for a long time (Sappho!) but not very much of it. So we should allow a wide definition of the very past and a wide geographic net, so to speak. Aside from written sources we could also consider pictures or statues as original sources.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I've edited. Hope it's better now.

Comment: Vastly improved. All questions should be supported by preliminary research, and the expectation is more rigorous when the question is fundamentally prurient or sensationalist.

Comment: The answer to question "Why do human females have breasts?" evolutionarily speaking, or so I was taught at university was "Because men like them".  https://www.livescience.com/32745-why-do-women-have-breasts.html

Comment: @AllInOne Sorry for late reply. I read that article just now. So according to that article/research, we can say evolution also played a role in evolving breasts and sexual attraction to them? Not just culture?

And you were taught similar things in university? Right?

Comment: @AllInOne and for that to be true at some extent, some African tribes would be exceptions as they don't find them sexually attractive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The very past" and "especially Victorian era" does not mix well, so it is unclear what era you are looking at.

"The very past" would, in my interpretation, be something like the [Venus of Willendorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_of_Willendorf) and other palaeolithic sculptures emphasizing breasts. Whether that is to indicate sexual attractiveness, or fertility, or if there is indeed a difference between the two for such early times, I leave open to interpretation.

Somewhat newer would be the Song of Solomon (e.g. 4:5 "Thy two breasts are like two young roes that are twins, which feed among the lilies.").

---

Breasts are part of the [sexual dimorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_dimorphism) of humans. Among other traits they *define* what we perceive as "female", like we perceive a muscular, breast-less upper body as "male". As such, it would be quite unnatural for a heterosexual male of our species to *not* perceive breasts as "sexy". Whether the preference is for them to be large or small, hidden or displayed, *that* certainly changed over time and under cultural influence.

Comment: the problem is, I read many Reddit answers, Quora answers and yahoo answers which try to say "it is just cultural". I wouldn't doubt it if they would say "culture also have a big role in it". So basically, I wanted to know if it really started when culture sexualized them. To *verify* this, I'm just looking for some references which say breasts were sexualized even before this.

Comment: So you're looking to escape a [false dichotomy fallacy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/false_dichotomy)?  <irony> the internet may be the wrong tool for that</irony>

Comment: For the record, I edited the question to remove the "very past" phrase referred to in the first paragraph.

Comment: @vivek Counterquestion. How *could* breasts *not* be sexualized, them being a gender trait and all?

Comment: @vivek - The problem there is that you are reading Quora and Yahoo Answers. At least the Yahoo problem is going away soon.

Comment: @T.E.D. the thing is many users among them have so much *reputations* on those networks, so I feel they may be right saying culture made them sexual attraction.

Comment: @DevSolar Good counterquestion. Two big reasons those users give and make me feel they are right: 1) Men in some Africa parts don't find breasts sexually attractive because for a long time women never hid them. Unlike other cultures.2) Men also have nipples. Why there not much evidence of sexual attraction to them as compared to breasts?

Comment: @vivek As long as you put more trust in Reddit hearsay than actual sources, I am afraid I cannot help you further.

Comment: @vivek Besides, you are changing the question. Did sexual attraction commonly exist? Sources say yes. Do exceptions exist? Of course, they always do.

Comment: @DevSolar the thing is there are people online who say breasts sexual attraction is just because of culture sexualized it. Just like ankles were sexualized in past. That's it. Nothing else. I don't know whether to believe it or not.

Comment: @DevSolar also, the article AllInOne user shared in comments on the original question, could make a sense. But to believe that, I must say some tribes are exceptions for that to be true to some extent. You mean that type of exceptions?

Comment: @vivek: I provided examples that cultures *way* before ours saw breasts as attractive. The other answer provided more examples. That IMHO falsifies the claim that "our" culture, let alone "western" culture, sexualized them and that they were not sexualized before, and makes "tribes in which breasts are not looked upon as sexy" (for which I'd have to see sources first) the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: @DevSolar makes sense. But still I find it hard to believe because so many people say it's just because culture sexualized it.

Answer (score 2):

The [1001 Nights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Thousand_and_One_Nights), collated from Middle Eastern folk tales quite a while before Victorian times (first English-language edition (c. 1706–1721)), is absolutely rife with descriptions such as *her breasts were like ripe pomegranates*.

Or look at [Angkor Wat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angkor_Wat), Cambodia, 12th century, sculptures.  Seems pretty clear to me that breasts are emphasized.

[image]

Looks like someone had a pet theory with some valid grounding that they tried to fit too much into.

Comment: You can find sexualization of breasts in the hottest sections of Tirant lo Blanch (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirant_lo_Blanch) (published in 1490).

Comment: So it's clear there's evidence of sexual attraction to breasts in past before Victorian era. Thanks for the answer. Now I don't know how to comfront people who say like most in men in today's world are attracted to breasts because society/culture made them sexual.

Comment: @vivek [You don't](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: @vivek That there is sexualization of breasts and that some cultures appear to be obsessed with them are two different things. We could say the same about any other part of the body, or nudity in general. Sex and nudity are only related in that most people likes to do sex while completely naked. We could say the same thing about having a shower. In most of Europe breasts were much less sexualized than in the USA, for example: topless in beaches, breastfeeding in public or even mixed sexes nude saunas are (or were) part of different modern western cultures.

Comment: @DevSolar you don't means? I didn't get that comic. Could you please explain?

Comment: @vivek That you should not put too much weight on what "people" say on the internet, and that it is futile trying to correct them.

Comment: @DevSolar thank you very much. I'm slightly less burdened now.